# How to use the return of regex match into another regex

Tags: javascript, regex

```
text = "I have usd **12** only."
var amount = text.match(\(?:USD|usd)\s+.? 
\d+\.?[0-9]{1,2}\);
```

it returns

```
usd *12
```

I'm trying to grab the number only out of this return?

Is it possible to use "amount" again like this:

```
amount.match(\\d+\.?[0-9]{1,2}\);
```

Comment: You should search for  'Groups' in regex, they will let you do it in one run.

Comment: `if (m=text.match(/\busd\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/i)) {
  console.log(m[1]);
}`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two regexes for this. This regex will do the job on its own:

```
(?:USD|usd)\s+.*?(\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?)
```

It will capture the number in a capture group, so you only need one regex:

```
"I have usd **12** only."           // -> 12
"I have usd 12.00 only."            // -> 12.00
"I have usd **** 12.00 **** only."  // -> 12.0
```

[**regex101 demo**](https://regex101.com/r/cGxLMN/2)